# Mysql index use B-tree or B+ tree

Tags: mysql

I've been told many times that mysql use B+ tree as index data structure, and [in this question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/204561/does-mysql-use-b-tree-btree-or-both) it also said index story in B+ tree. But I find something different in Mysql official document, in [mysql indexes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-indexes.html) it says `Most MySQL indexes (PRIMARY KEY, UNIQUE, INDEX, and FULLTEXT) are stored in B-trees`

so I wonder which one is right, B-Tree or B+ tree?

Comment: You do not believe the official User Manual?

Comment: @Akina I do believe the official, but there are so many people told me Mysql index use B+ tree, in China we have a proverb `三人成虎` means: a lie, if repeated often enough, will be accepted as truth. so I post this question

Comment: No words.. ask somebody from these "many people" to prove that MySQL index is actually B+ and not B..

Comment: @Akina any I am curious why so many people are wrong, and how do they come to the conclusion that index in mysql is B+ tree

Comment: People like to repeat after someone without thinking - it's easy.

Answer (score 0):

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/innodb-fil-header.html

You can look at this sentence in the documentation:

> This is a sophistication which you won't find in the classic B-tree, which is why InnoDB should perhaps be called a B+-tree instead